# automatic annotation image using SVM

Tags: matlab, matlab-cvst, matlab-deployment, glcm

I have extracted features of an segmented image (mamogram image) using GLCM

```
I = imread('IMAGE1.jpg'); 
GLCM = graycomatrix(I,'Offset',[2 0;0 2]); 
stats = graycoprops(GLCM,'all') 
t1 = struct2array(stats)
```

Now I want to classify using SVM, please help how to process

Comment: I ran your code on a sample image and found `t1 =
    0.1183    0.1291    0.9888    0.9878    0.1111    0.1090    0.9424    0.9375` ... What exactly are you trying to classify?